# Running a Selenium webscraper in AWS Lambda using Docker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium, aws-lambda

I am trying to create a simple python Lambda app using SAM CLI that gets the number of followers for a particular handle. Have looked at ALL tutorials and blog posts and yet have not been able to make it work.

The build and local test works fine using `sam build` and `sam local invoke`, however, after deployment to AWS Lambda it throws the following error.

Any ideas how to solve this?

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.\n  (chrome not reachable)\n  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)\n",
  "errorType": "WebDriverException",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/app.py\", line 112, in main\n    data = Twitter(StockInfo_list)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/app.py\", line 36, in Twitter\n    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path, options=chrome_optionsdata)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py\", line 76, in __init__\n    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py\", line 157, in __init__\n    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py\", line 252, in start_session\n    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py\", line 321, in execute\n    self.error_handler.check_response(response)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py\", line 242, in check_response\n    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)\n"
  ]
}
```

I'm using the following as my Dockerfile

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

# Update repository and install unzip
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install unzip -y

# Download and install Google Chrome
COPY curl https://intoli.com/install-google-chrome.sh | bash

# Download and install ChromeDriver
RUN CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=`curl -sS https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE` && \
    wget -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin/
RUN echo $(chromedriver --version)

# Upgrade PIP
RUN /var/lang/bin/python3.8 -m pip install --upgrade pip

# Install requirements (including selenium)
COPY app.py requirements.txt ./
RUN python3.8 -m pip install -r requirements.txt -t .

# Command can be overwritten by providing a different command in the template directly.
CMD ["app.main"]
```

My applications looks like

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import os
import time, datetime
import pandas as pd
import csv


# import mysql.connector
from datetime import date, datetime as dt1


def Twitter(twitter_stock_id):

    twitterlist = []
    stockids = []
    twitterlist = twitter_stock_id["TwitterUrl"].str.lower().tolist()
    
    stockids = twitter_stock_id["stockid"].str.lower().tolist()

    chrome_optionsdata = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2}
    chrome_optionsdata.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    chrome_optionsdata.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_optionsdata.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_optionsdata.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    chrome_optionsdata.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    chrome_optionsdata.add_argument("--disable-gpu-sandbox")

    chromedriver_path = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path, options=chrome_optionsdata)

    lfollowers = []

    for url in twitterlist:

        tempurl = driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(10)
        followers = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("r-qvutc0")
        for fol in followers:
            if "Followers" in fol.text:
                tempstr = fol.text.split(" ")
                lfollowers.append(tempstr[0])

        time.sleep(5)

    
    lmaindata = []
    for fld in lfollowers:
        if fld != "Followers":
            lmaindata.append(fld)

    print("Followers" + str(lmaindata))
    driver.quit()
    return f"Followers: {lmaindata}"


import json


def main(event, context):
    StockInfo_list = pd.DataFrame([{"TwitterUrl": "https://twitter.com/costco", "stockid": "COST"}])
    data = Twitter(StockInfo_list)

    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps({"message": "hello", "data": data}),
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were three key issues why this script didn't work

1. Lambda restricts write to `/tmp/` folder
2. The executables were not a locaiton in `PATH`
3. Missing dependencies for Chromium

To fix this,

1. I appropriated a shell script that downloads a specific version of Chromium & Chromium webdriver that are compatible into `/tmp/` folder and then installed them at `/opt/`.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

declare -A chrome_versions

# Enter the list of browsers to be downloaded
### Using Chromium as documented here - https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium
chrome_versions=( ['89.0.4389.47']='843831' )
chrome_drivers=( "89.0.4389.23" )
#firefox_versions=( "86.0" "87.0b3" )
#gecko_drivers=( "0.29.0" )

# Download Chrome
for br in "${!chrome_versions[@]}"
do
    echo "Downloading Chrome version $br"
    mkdir -p "/opt/chrome/stable"
    curl -Lo "/opt/chrome/stable/chrome-linux.zip" \
    "https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-snapshots/o/Linux_x64%2F${chrome_versions[$br]}%2Fchrome-linux.zip?alt=media"
    unzip -q "/opt/chrome/stable/chrome-linux.zip" -d "/opt/chrome/stable/"
    mv /opt/chrome/stable/chrome-linux/* /opt/chrome/stable/
    rm -rf /opt/chrome/stable/chrome-linux "/opt/chrome/stable/chrome-linux.zip"
done

# Download Chromedriver
for dr in ${chrome_drivers[@]}
do
    echo "Downloading Chromedriver version $dr"
    mkdir -p "/opt/chromedriver/stable/"
    curl -Lo "/opt/chromedriver/stable//chromedriver_linux64.zip" \
    "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$dr/chromedriver_linux64.zip"
    unzip -q "/opt/chromedriver/stable//chromedriver_linux64.zip" -d "/opt/chromedriver/stable/"
    chmod +x "/opt/chromedriver/stable/chromedriver"
    rm -rf "/opt/chromedriver/stable/chromedriver_linux64.zip"
done

echo "Chrome & Chromedriver installed"
```

2. Changed the Dockerfile to the following

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8 as base

# Hack to install chromium dependencies
RUN yum install -y -q unzip
RUN yum install -y https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm

# Install Chromium
COPY install-browser.sh /tmp/
RUN /usr/bin/bash /tmp/install-browser.sh

#FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8
# Install Python dependencies for function
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip -q
RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt -q


COPY app.py ./

CMD [ "app.handler" ]
```

And finally, the missing dependencies were also solved within this docker file by installing `Chrome` directly that brought with itself 122 packages that were needed to run Chrome.

I've put this in a [GitHub Repository here](https://github.com/rehanhaider/selenium-in-aws-lambda) and explained the steps in a [blog post here](https://cloudbytes.dev/articles/run-selenium-in-aws-lambda-for-ui-testing).